# WPF - class property as data trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm having this code where I would like to update the image in my main window when the property in a usercontrol changes. But somehow I can't get the trigger working.

Some of the XAML code

```
<StatusBar MinHeight="10" MaxHeight="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="2">
    <Image x:Name="SomeNameHere">
        <Image.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=pingable}" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="Icons/MainWindow/StatusOffline_stop_32x.png"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=pingable}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="Icons/MainWindow/StatusOK_32x.png"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
</StatusBar>
```

The part where the property comes from

```
public bool pingable { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pingable = PingHost("some random IP");
}

public bool PingHost(string nameOrAddress)
{
    pingable = false;
    Ping pinger = new Ping();
    try
    {
        PingReply reply = pinger.Send(nameOrAddress);
        pingable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
    }
    catch (PingException)
    {
        // Discard PingExceptions and return false;
    }
    return pingable;
}
```

I see the property during debugging in the XAML editor so it seemingly gets recognized and I also see the value would fit. But somehow the setter doesn't get executed.
Someone an idea on this?

Thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to raise your `PropertyChanged` event on `pingable` to get the view to update.

Basically, in order to get the view to know that it needs to update some control based on a binding, your view model needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`; any time you want the update the view based on a change in the view model, you need to raise `PropertyChanged` from the view model and pass it the name of the bound property whose value was updated.

Comment: Thanks to you. That actually helped me quite much. Will post a reply with how I handled it in the end in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you RaisePropertyChanged on the getter and setter, it will notify the XAML when the property changes and make the triggers fire.
Try this code:

```
 bool _pingable;
 public bool pingable 
 {
    get{return _pingable;} 
    set{ _pingable = value; RaisePropertyChanged;}
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other two answers before mine point out that `INotifyPropertyChanged` needs to be implemented -- and that is somewhat important for a normal WPF application -- I don't believe that actually matters here. Your ping request looks synchronous, so the UI isn't actually going to be loaded by the time you update your value, making `INotifyPropertyChanged` irrelevant.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Thread.Sleep(2000);  // pretending to ping
        Flag = true;
    }

    public bool Flag { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Flag}" />
</Grid>
```

This is checked when the window eventually loads. If this were asynchronous, it would be a different story.

> I see the property during debugging in the XAML editor

I'm not sure what this means. I suspect the actual problem here is that you don't have a DataContext defined. (Maybe it is, but I can't see it here!)

You've created the property *on the window* itself, so... what if you switched your trigger to be...

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=pingable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Value="false">
```